# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured. When I tried running a python program on my local machine, I encounted this error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I tried running a python program on my local machine, I encountered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 50, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

There are also similar posts online, and I tried the suggested solution from each post, but none of them could solve my error.

Here is the content of my setting.py

My python version: Python 3.7.3
My Django verison: 2.2

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku 
import dj_database_url

config = dj_database_url.config

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
DEBUG = False

# Experimenting here
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "https://stormy-stream-43261.herokuapp.com/"]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
# from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

# def get_env_variable(var_name):
#     try:
#         return os.environ[var_name]
#     except KeyError:
#         error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
#         raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

# one for development (maybe move that to local postgres) and another for running and development
DATABASES = {

    # 'default': {
    #    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    #    'NAME': 'xsboediz',
    #    'USER': 'xsboediz',
    #    'PASSWORD': 'Qcn3tmpnSgp1QHgk_dsCvukFFPJAofm0',
    #    'HOST': 'baasu.db.elephantsql.com',
    #    'PORT': '5432'
    # }

    #
    # 'default': dj_database_url.config(
    #     default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    # )
    #

    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        }


}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

#STATIC_URL = './blog/staticfiles/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     #'/Diversity_Policy_Site/blog/static',
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
# )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910638/when-i-tried-running-my-python-program-i-encountered-a-django-importing-module

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment or remove this 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
in settings.py in MIDDLEWARE [].

Comment: I just tried this solution, but it showed an error:                                                  
ERRORS:
?: (admin.E408) 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.